# Selecting multiple tables PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issues with this code, it's displaying multiple of the same table headings and I don't know why.

**Heres the code :**

```
#This section of code will display my affected_countries table
echo"<br><br>This will list and display important information about the statistics of the infections<br>";
$sql = "SELECT * from affected_countries,infection_info";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

echo"<table border='1'><tbody>";
echo"<tr><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Country Origin</b></td><td><b>Number of Countries affected</b></td></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo"<tr><td>{$row['NAME']}</td><td>{$row['Country Origin']}</td><td>{$row['Number of Countries affected']}</td></tr>";
}
echo"</tbody></table><br>";
```

**Output on website:** 
[Two Tables above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k66vX.png)
[Table below(Issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guop4.png)
It just has multiple of the same thing and I don't know what I should do

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is not a PHP question. Also PHPMYADMIN is just a UI for interacting with a mysql DB. That is unrelated to your issue. Look up `sql join` and also your current join syntax is +20 years old. Use `join`s.

Comment: I cannot see why these are separate tables

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SQL joins to get columns from multiple tables.
See the example query:

`SELECT ac.name, ii.country_origin, ii.number_of_countries_affected FROM affected_countries ac INNER JOIN infection_info ON ac.name =ii.name;`

Answer (score 0):

You should list from two tables separately

```
$sqlAffected = "SELECT * from affected_countries";
$sqlinfection_info = "SELECT * from infection_info";

$resultA = mysqli_query($db, $sqlAffected);
$resultB = mysqli_query($db, $sqlinfection_info);
```

or something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM affected_countries UNION infection_info;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM affected_countries LEFT JOIN infection_info on afftected_countries.primary_key = infection_info.affected_country_id;
```

Comment: When I use the first one you suggested, nothing comes under the table when I open the website.

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: SELECT * is valid, if you know the database and the columns, it doesn't matters